# UI Automation GetFocusedElement returning root element

Tags: c++, winapi, ui-automation

I am trying to determine if the focused element can accept input.
I'm using `GetFocusedElement` of UI Automation API.

However when I make the call it is returning the root element and not the actual element with the focus.

If I try the same thing with Inspect.exe, and set it to follow focus, it correctly identifies the correct control.

What additional steps do I need to do to find the actual control element with focus?

Below is a screen grab from Inspect showing the correct control highlighted.
When I make a call to GetFocusedElement it returns the parent 'General' element.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the return value of the [`GetFocusedElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uiautomationclient/nf-uiautomationclient-iuiautomation-getfocusedelement) function? Is it `S_OK` or `HRESULT` error code?

Comment: Yes, the `HRESULT` is `S_OK` and a valid element is returned, just not the one with the keyboard focus.

Comment: I can reproduce this issue you can check the detailed information [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/abaaa455-dee7-46d4-b3bb-d376ddcd7067/getfocusedelement-returns-root-element-insted-of-focused-element?forum=windowsaccessibilityandautomation#45a4f1aa-3d29-47b5-bf7f-767111641222).